# JQuery element on click stops firing after body on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

On tablet resolutions I have a menu dropdown. I have an on click function that displays a background overlay and changes the menu icon, which is working fine when I click it once.

I then have another on click function to remove the overlay and change the menu icon back when clicking anywhere on the body of the page. This currently works too.

The problem is, after I have clicked anywhere on the page to trigger the body on click function, and then go to click the Menu dropdown, the Menu dropdown on click function isn't firing there after.

Here are the two on click functions -

```
// The dropdown menu on click function to display the overlay & change menu icon

$('.tablet-menu').on("click", function(e) {
    if($('#overlay').css('display')=='none') {
       $("#overlay").fadeIn(800);
       $(this).find(".dropdown-icon").removeClass("fa fa-angle-down").addClass("fas fa-times");
    }
 });

// The body on click function to remove the overlay and change back menu icon

$('body').on("click", function (e) {
    var container = $('.tablet-menu');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('#overlay').remove();
       $(this).find(".dropdown-icon").removeClass("fas fa-times").addClass("fa fa-angle-down");
     } 
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="tablet-menu">
   <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="tabletMenu" data- 
      toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu
       <i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-angle-down pl-1"</i>
    </button>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a class="tablet_menu" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
            <li>
               <button class="tablet_menu" id="TabletMenuContent">
                    Content
                </button>
                    <div class="TabletMenuContent hidden">
                        <button class="menu-back" parent="TabletMenuContent"> 
                           <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span> Back
                        </button>
                      <div class="col-6 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url %}">Places</a>
                            </div>
                      </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**master.css**

```
#overlay {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow-x: auto;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background: Grey;
}
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

**Update**

Thank you A K, Dharman and Dejan Cavic for correcting the `.remove()` with `.hide()`.

After making this change, I've noticed another body on click function that is hiding the main dropdown menu when a sub menu is open. This just makes space and less messy with both open at the same time.

I previously thought this function is stopping the overlay and icons from changing after clicking the body.

But what is happening is -

When I click the body of the page then go to click then dropdown Menu, the dropdown Menu opens and the overlay does not appear, then when I click on a dropdown menu item, it opens the sub menu and hides the main Menu and the overlay then shows and the icon changes.

Here is the other body on click function. I have also updated the HTML to show the sub menus in the dropdown.

```
$("body").on("click tap", ".tablet_menu", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var element = $(this);
    $('.'+ element.attr('id')).toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.tablet-menu').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Should've posted this function in the beginning.
I am going to need to find the best way to incorporate these functionalities without them conflicting.

Comment: Please always include the minimal code in order to run your application so that we can replicate your issue and provide an answer. In your case, that means editing your question and including the relevant CSS and HTML.

Comment: Is your problem only overlay not fading in or both overlay and dropdown classes not being added after you click on body?

Comment: @AK Yes, it is just the overlay that is not fading in. It is like the `$('.tablet-menu').on("click", function(e)` is no longer firing after clicking the body and triggering the `$('body').on("click", function (e)`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Certainly, I have updated with the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @bensmi, you are deleting it on body click, so when you click on menu element there is no overlay element to appear. You must use `$('#overlay')..hide()` instead of `$('#overlay').remove();` so that the element stays in HTML

Comment: @AK Thank you very much, of course. I have updated the question with further findings